# How Can I Remove All Targets In Url In Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

If I want to show specific part of page in using `#id` in the url.

so for example my url is:

> `www.example.com/#geometry`

When I reload my page I want all the targets (`#geometry`) on the url to be removed before reload. So there would be only `www.example.com`.

How can I do this?

Update:
i don't know what my url be it is generated from server side see this my url

```
       localhost:8080/home?requestParams=%7B%22tabMode%22
```

and now to view any part of that page i add

```
       #id
```

so it becomes

```
     localhost:8080/home?requestParams=%7B%22tabMode%22#geometry
```

, now on reload of this page i want to remove this #geometry how can i do it any idea?

Comment: i want that whenever i click on reload or any button that reloads the page , the id in url should disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> location.hash='';

At the start of your script.

Comment: i don't know what my url be it is generated from server side see this my url 
http://localhost:8080/home?requestParams=%7B%22tabMode%22
and now to view any part of that page i add #id so it becomes 
http://localhost:8080/home?requestParams=%7B%22tabMode%22#geometry, now on reload of this page i want to remove this #geometry how can i do it any idea